# How to put title slug into content when create a new post?

Tags: slug, title

After finish type the title post from the title field, i want to put the slug automatically inside the content .. can i do this ?

ex Title : This is just an example

Permalink : example.com/this-is-just-an-example

Content : this-is-just-an-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `the_content` filter.

Following example is to just adds a featured image set from the single post Edit screen which displays before the content on single posts only.

You can change it to display title and  permalink.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'featured_image_before_content' ); 

 function featured_image_before_content( $content ) { 
    if ( is_singular('post') && has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail();

        $content = $thumbnail . $content;

        }

    return $content;
}
```

Source : [Plugin API/Filter Reference/the content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content)